# wrong output with serial in C

Tags: c, serial-port, posix

I am trying to send data over a serial line in C. I suspect my problem lies in the options I've set, but I can't figure it out.

In the following program, I'm sending the bytes 0x79, 0x80, 0x81, but at the other end, I'm receiving 0x86, 0x06, 0x00

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

/*
 * 'open_port()' - Open serial port 1.
 *
 * Returns the file descriptor on success or -1 on error.
 */
char SERIAL_DEVICE[] = {"/dev/ttyUSB0"};
struct termios options;

void open_port(int* fd)
{
    *fd = open(SERIAL_DEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    if (*fd == -1){
        /* Could not open the port. */
        perror("open_port: Unable to open serial port - ");

    } else 
        fcntl(*fd, F_SETFL, 0);

}

void send(int message[], size_t bytes_to_send, int* fd){
    int n,i;

    for(i=0;i<bytes_to_send;i++){
        printf("%x", message[i]);
    }
    n = write(*fd, message, bytes_to_send);
    if (n < 0)
      fputs("write() failed!\n", stderr);
}

int main(){

    int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */

    int message[] = {0x79, 0x80, 0x81};

    // load the options structure with the cuurent port options
    tcgetattr(fd, &options);        
    cfsetispeed(&options, B19200); // set in baudrate
    cfsetospeed(&options, B19200); // set out baudrate
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

    // No Parity 8N1
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;
    options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    options.c_iflag |= (IGNPAR | ISTRIP);

    //raw input and output
    options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    // Flush buffers and set new options
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &options);

    open_port(&fd);

    int array_length = sizeof(message) / sizeof(message[0]);    
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<array_length;i++){
        printf("%x", message[i]);
    }

    send(message, array_length, &fd);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your termios stuff is ineffective. You are changing the terminal characteristics of a random file descriptor (`fd` is uninitialized) because you are opening the serial port AFTER doing `tcsetattr`. If you checked for errors on the `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr` calls, you would have caught this. Also, you would have caught it if you were paying attention to warnings emitted by your compiler.

Then, there are two problems with your `send` function:

- It has the same name as the `send` system call. This is technically OK since your `send` overrides the `send` from libc and everything works, but it's confusing (when I first read the code I thought you were using the `send` system call) and dangerous (in case you are using the `send` system call elsewhere in your program).
- It passes an array of `int`s to `write`, but `write` expects an array of bytes. As a result, when you try to write 0x79, you end up writing the 4 bytes 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x79 (for big-endian 32 bit platform) or 0x79 0x00 0x00 0x00 (for little-endian 32 bit platform).

Comment: perfect. I need to spend more time on error handling. I just compiled with -Wall and hoped for the best. switched to char for the data type, now I'm getting more of what I expected.